# wpf & visual studio

Tags: wpf

after creating a wpf visual studio 2010 project - i noticed there is no "open in expression blend" link as there is in a silverlight 4 project. I found out so far that expression blend 4 should be present before installing visual studio 2010. (This means if you do the reverse having visual studio 2010 and then installing expression blend 4 afterwards, then the above link will not be shown) The work around is to use the "open with" in visual studio 2010 project by right clicking
the xaml folder and adding the proper expression blend program you want, clicking it afterwaards
and after getting the "error message of the xaml folder" and closing it, open up the same project
as in visual studio 2010 - and then you have a link.  This is unneceasary in a silverlight project.

Anybody can clerify this because I DO NOT WANT TO UNINSTALL AND REINSTALL VISUAL STUDIO 2010 and
when changing "regedit" is different for a windows 7 64x than it is for 32x.